# Listen to ModalBottomSheet close

Tags: dart, flutter

how to execute a block of code when the user close Modal Bottom Sheet ?

```
showModalBottomSheet(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return new MusicR();
          },
        )
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can assign your `showModalBottomSheet` into a `Future`.

What will happen is that the user will trigger the close action on the modal sheet and trigger the `then` callback on your future variable.

Example:

```
Future<void> bottomSheetAwaitClose = showModalBottomSheet<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  },
);

bottomSheetAwaitClose.then((void value) => print ("Bottom sheet closed"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Code below prints 'null' after closing bottom sheet

```
test() async {
  dynamic x = await showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) => Container(height: 200.0, color: Colors.green,) );
  print('$x');
  // some other actions
}
```